# Group Email for Azure Log Analytics Query Result

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

Hi i am new to Azure.

My Requirement is i have to send **Log Analytics Query Result** to **Group Email**.How to give Group Email id For Azure Action Group? Currently it is accepting single Mail id, it's not accepting Mail Id's with semi colon. I tried by giving Group Mail Id to the Particular Action Group, but it's not sending Alert to Group.

**note**: I don't want to use Logic Apps to send Group Email

**Action Group Path  : Azure -> Monitor -> Alerts -> Manage Actions**

Please Help me out for this problem, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this built-in action does not allow you to specify multiple email addresses.

Here are some alternative solutions:

1. Define one action for each email address in the action group
2. Build a generic function to send emails to a list of recipients (array)

You can bring this feedback to the product team as this seems like is a valid requirement [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/913690-azure-monitor).

Comment: Thank you @L M Gagne for quick response,how to build generic function meaning how to send log analytics query result to generic function? is something like create a method in function app and pass parameters like list of email addresses with query result? Basically  i am using Azure Data Factory(ADF), for this i have some pipelines, so i want to know whether my pipeline is success or fail through Email. So to get Pipeline Result i build Some Query something like `ADFPipelineRun | where Status == "Succeeded"  or Status == "Failed"`. I want this query result to Group Email.

Comment: From my understanding, you are already redirecting your logs into a log analytics workspace. Then, a Kusto query is executed and then, the built-in action is triggered to send an email. Since the built-in action does not allow multiple addresses, the idea is to call a rest api of your own that would handle the email aspect of the process.

Comment: yes,exactly this is what i am doing, OK i will try with rest API . Thank you so much @L M Gagne.

Comment: You can use a distribution list email instead as well.

Comment: How to send distribution list Email , I tried Actually but it is not sending , can you tell me the steps to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since all you can do is to send to one email recipient, this can be either an individual email address or a distribution list (generic email address that contains more than 1 email address).

Comment: yes @L M Gagne, i tried this way also but it is not sending(ex: i added more than 1 email address and created a group in outlook and then trying to give this group email  id to action group, but no luck)..

Comment: This distribution list must be created in exchange. This is something I use and it is working.

Comment: Thank you @L M Gagne, Exchange server is only accessible to system administrators ? Can  you please send me if you have any link that would me more helpful..